# Sequelize update not working when updating aliased updateAt attribute only

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

after upgrading to sequlize v5 (from 4.x.x) this one stopped working:

```
await myModel.update({
    date_updated: new Date()
  }, {
    where: {
      id: obj.id
    }
});
```

I have that field aliased for `updatedAt` in my model obviously:

```
...
updatedAt: 'date_updated',
...
```

And I just found it’s because of this impl in sequelize’s model.js:

```
// only updatedAt is being passed, then skip update
if (
  _.isEmpty(valuesUse)
   || Object.keys(valuesUse).length === 1 && valuesUse[this._timestampAttributes.updatedAt]
) {
  return [0];
}
```

… which will skip the update.

The issue is it will not set the value for date_updated attribute = not update the instance at all. Is it bug or feature? Any ideas for the workaround?

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3759#issuecomment-151862693) help?

Comment: How exactly should I use that one? Try to `findOne()` & `changed()` & `save()` instead of `Model.update()`? Also, call `changed()` for original or aliased attribute?

Comment: If  you have initialized the attribute with an alias e.g: ```columnA: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE,
    field: 'column_a'
  }``` then do always use the alias you stated e.g: ```columnA```. And yes find the instance then call changed followed by save. ```instance.changed('updatedAt', true);
instance.save();```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is still open issue right now mentioning also this case:
https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3759

As @MAS pointed in the comment, one possible workaround stated there is `instance.changed('updatedAt', true)`.

I actually prefer the other one, to avoid *get - set - save* sequence:

```
await myModel.update({
    // fake to make update happen
    id: obj.id
    date_updated: new Date()
  }, {
    where: {
      id: obj.id
    }
});
```